# Ruby on Rails model inside namespace can't be found in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, namespaces

I'm new to rails and can't figure out this issue...

I have a controller

```
Admin::Blog::EntriesController
```

defined in app/controllers/admin/blog/entries_controller.rb

And I have a model called

```
Blog::Entry
```

defined in app/model/blog/entry.rb

When I try to access my model from the controller, I get a `"uninitialized constant Admin::Blog::EntriesController::Blog"` from this line:

```
@blog_entries = Blog::Entry.find(:all)
```

Clearly it is not finding the namespace correctly which is odd because according to what I have read, I have placed my model in the correct folder with the correct syntax.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try:

```
@blog_entries = ::Blog::Entry.find(:all)
```

It's currently looking for the wrong class.  Using `::` before `Blog` will force it to look from the top level.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that did work. However, it turns out that I have to set a custom table name for my model as well. Also, the form_for helper dosn't work as it uses "<model path>_path" thing for the action attribute I think, so it throws an error that it can't find the method "blog_entries_path"... Any ideas?

Comment: I'm starting to think that rails frowns upon multiple namespaces for models and controllers... Which is a shame because I really like the <section>/<module>/<model> path structure.

Comment: the rails convention is that model names are singular while controllers are plural.  Maybe rename the controller Admins::Blogs::EntriesController (yes, that looks strange)

Maybe you should also rethink using namespaced models, they are probably more trouble than they're worth, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601768/namespaced-models-in-rails-whats-the-state-of-the-union

Comment: This also solves the issue I encountered when accidentally duplicating a class name later found in an SDK. My model's class started resolving to the API namespace in files that included the SDK, so adding :: in front forced it back into the main app namespace, which properly resolved to my class name again.

Answer (score 3):

It is now 2011 and we are in Rails 3.1 territory, but this issue still arises. I just ran into it with a namespaced controller referencing a non-namespaced model, *but only when there were no rows for that model in the database!*

Prefixing the model name with :: fixes the problem.

Comment: Was running into this with some tests in Rails 4. Creating an empty yml fixture for the model fixed it, but the underlying issue was actually *having a namespace the same name as a model*.

Comment: Could you believe that it's 2018 and the same issue is still there. :) Solved it by prefixing the model with :: as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve a custom table name by using

```
set_table_name('foo')
```

at the top of your model.

As for multiple namespaces, you might be able to get away with using

```
polymorphic_path(@the_object)
```

to generate your urls as it does more basic inference (in my experience at least, maybe form_for uses it under the hood).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, from looking at the code form_for uses polymorphic_path under the hood.