# Ruby on rails model and controllers inside of different namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, namespaces, form-for

OK. This is insane.

I'm new to RoR and I really want to get into it as everything about it that I have seen so far makes it more appealing to the type of work that I do.

However, I can't seem to accomplish a *very* simple thing with RoR.

I want these controlers:

```
/admin/blog/entries (index/show/edit/delete)
/admin/blog/categories (index/show/edit/delete)
/admin/blog/comments (index/show/edit/delete)
... and so on
```

And these models:

```
Blog::Entry    (table: blog_entries)
Blog::Category (table: blog_categories)
Blog::Comments (table: blog_comments)
... and so on
```

Now, I have already gone though quite a bit of misery to make this work. My first attempt was with generating scaffolding (I'm using 2.2.2). I generated my scaffolding, but had to move my model, then fix the references to the model in my controller (see [Ruby on Rails model inside namespace can't be found in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903258/ruby-on-rails-model-inside-namespace-cant-be-found-in-controller)).

That is already a big of a pain, but hey, I got it to work. Now though form_for won't work and I cannot figure out how to use the url helpers (I have no idea what these are called... they are the automatically generated methods that return URLs to controllers associated with a model). I cannot figure out what their name is. My model is Blog::Entries. I have tried to mess with the route.rb's map's resource method, but no luck. When I attempt to use form_for with my model, I get this error

```
undefined method `blog_entries_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0xb6848080>
```

Now. This is really quite frustrating. I am not going to completely destroy my code's organization in order to use this framework, and if I cannot figure out how to accomplish this simple task (I have been researching this for at least 5 hours) then I simply cannot continue.

Are there any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here are my routes:

```
             admin_blog_entries GET    /admin_blog_entries                  {:controller=>"admin_blog_entries", :action=>"index"}
   formatted_admin_blog_entries GET    /admin_blog_entries.:format          {:controller=>"admin_blog_entries", :action=>"index"}
                                POST   /admin_blog_entries                  {:controller=>"admin_blog_entries", :action=>"create"}
                                POST   /admin_blog_entries.:format          {:controller=>"admin_blog_entries", :action=>"create"}
           new_admin_blog_entry GET    /admin_blog_entries/new              {:controller=>"admin_blog_entries", :action=>"new"}
 formatted_new_admin_blog_entry GET    /admin_blog_entries/new.:format      {:controller=>"admin_blog_entries", :action=>"new"}
          edit_admin_blog_entry GET    /admin_blog_entries/:id/edit         {:controller=>"admin_blog_entries", :action=>"edit"}
formatted_edit_admin_blog_entry GET    /admin_blog_entries/:id/edit.:format {:controller=>"admin_blog_entries", :action=>"edit"}
               admin_blog_entry GET    /admin_blog_entries/:id              {:controller=>"admin_blog_entries", :action=>"show"}
     formatted_admin_blog_entry GET    /admin_blog_entries/:id.:format      {:controller=>"admin_blog_entries", :action=>"show"}
                                PUT    /admin_blog_entries/:id              {:controller=>"admin_blog_entries", :action=>"update"}
                                PUT    /admin_blog_entries/:id.:format      {:controller=>"admin_blog_entries", :action=>"update"}
                                DELETE /admin_blog_entries/:id              {:controller=>"admin_blog_entries", :action=>"destroy"}
                                DELETE /admin_blog_entries/:id.:format      {:controller=>"admin_blog_entries", :action=>"destroy"}
                           home        /                                    {:action=>"index", :controller=>"index"}
                                       /:controller/:action/:id
                                       /:controller/:action/:id.:format
```

That dosn't look right. Here is my routes.rb (comments removed):

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|

  map.resources :admin_blog_entries

  map.home '', :controller => 'index'

  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
end
```

Comment: Out of interest, do you have other Entry, Category and Comment models within your application? I'm curious as to why you've decided to put them within a namespace.

Comment: Are you putting the namespace into the form for and link to?

    form_for(:blog, @entry) do etc.

Though you may be better off using nested associations. It looks like you're overcomplicating it.

Comment: John: I like to organize my projects in such a way that each "module" is separated. Rather then use underscores (blog_entries, blog_categories) I want to put them in a separate folder.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your routes.rb ? How are you generating your routes? Are you using the #resource method?

Answer (score 2):

have you tried looking at the routes list that "rake routes" gives you? if your routes.rb is correct, it should show you the correct name for the blog entries route.

also, maybe this can help: http://www.coreywoodcox.com/2008/08/18/rails-namespaces-subdomains/.

edit:

well, then the correct way to call the route is admin_blog_entries_path instead of blog_entries_path.

Answer (score 1):

Your routes.rb should look like this:

```
map.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.namespace :blog do |blog|
    blog.resources :entries
    blog.resources :categories
    ...
  end
end
```

but I'm not sure how to handle this '/blog/' part in your url (I didn't use any namespace in my models yet). But with these routes you will be able to use:

```
admin_blog_categories_path               => '/admin/blog/categiries'
admin_blog_category_path(@some_category) => '/admin/blog/categories/1'
```

and so on.

Comment: The '/blog/' part can be added by 'scope "/blog" do...end'

Answer (score 1):

OK, here my rather hacky way of doing it, which I don't like but does work.

In my case I have the models Blog::Article, Blog::Comment, they are nested in the routes. One caveat if using this approach is in the Blog::CommentsController when loading the article you can expect params[:article_id] or params[:blog_article_id]. By no means nice, but like I said. It does work :/

```
blog.resources :articles do |article|
  article.resources :comments
end

blog.resources :blog_articles, :controller => 'articles' do |blog_article|
  blog_article.resources :blog_comments, :controller => 'comments'
end
```