# Rails Controller in nested module cannot resolve model in module with the same

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails model located at *app/models/scheduling/availability.rb* which looks like:

```
class Scheduling::Availability < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I have a Rails controller located at *app/controllers/admin/scheduling/availabilities_controller.rb* which looks like:

```
class Admin::Scheduling::AvailabilitiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @availabilities = Scheduling::Availability.all
  end
end
```

My routes look like:

```
namespace :admin do
  namespace :scheduling do
    resources :availabilities
  end
end
```

When trying to load the url:
*/admin/scheduling/availabilities*
I get the error:

> uninitialized constant
>   Admin::Scheduling::AvailabilitiesController::Scheduling

I have a feeling this is because Rails is confusing the Scheduling module/namespaces.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have resourceful routing setup for your instructors controller, but I don't see anything for availability?

Comment: Was an error in my posting...updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer in [another answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903258/ruby-on-rails-model-inside-namespace-cant-be-found-in-controller)

Need to preface my module with ::

```
class Admin::Scheduling::AvailabilitiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @availabilities = ::Scheduling::Availability.all
  end
end
```