# Stop Rails Console from loading Test::Unit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testunit, rails-console

I have a model named "Test" (I commented everything out of that model so all that's left is `class Test` `end` for debugging purposes) and every time I try instantiating it in the rails console I get an error that the "new" method does not exist for `Test:Module`.  This error does not occur when instantiating any of my other models, and I think it has to do with the fact that the rails console is loading up Test::Unit or something like that (on a hunch I ran `Test.constants` and the console returned `[:Unit]`, so I am pretty sure that's the issue).  At any rate, there is no question that some module named Test is being run by the rails console, and I don't want this to happen.  How do I avoid this?  It would be highly inconvenient for me to change me class name to a different value, so if there is any way to resolve this issue that would be great~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used a simple work-around of calling my class "Exam" instead of Test, but I would like to know how to resolve this correctly without working around the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a module and have your test class inside of it to avoid that issue. You will then need to address your class like module::class.

Comment: I feel like this approach is a little messy - I would much rather have a piece of code run that "undefines" the Test class that the rails console seems to be reading in.  Also, if I did use this encapsulating module approach, what would the implications be for the rest of my code (database access, etc.)?

Comment: Also, I have been looking around online and apparently namespaced models are an absolute hassle / mess in Rails -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601768/namespaced-models-in-rails-whats-the-state-of-the-union.  So I really need rails console to just not load Test::Unit.

Comment: It's not messy, that is exactly what modules are for. You were just trying to add methods to an already defined class. You either don't name your class after an already predefined class or put yours inside a module. Or yes like you said remove Test all together but thats like saying you want to remove puts because the ruby puts is interfering with your puts.

Comment: I suppose you're right - probably not the wisest of moves to be messing with the rails magic